# Running a test from an API in regular application context instead of test context

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cucumber, spring-boot-test, cucumber-java

I would like to create a cucumber test application that will take a Feature file from API input like POST- @RequestBody and then run the test for the file. From my research, I don't see any possible way to do it instead of setting up everything in @SpringBootTest, include the test file in resource and then run `mvn test`. This isn't a very good way to run a test because you have to go into the app to add or modify the scenario file then run the test. Running the test from an API with file input would be a lot easier for someone else to use since the goal of cucumber is making it human friendly without a lot of coding.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution valid. Although, it doesn't provide you a shell.

- Create a normal application with test unit.
- Make sure maven/gradle is installed and added to PATH
- Inside the regular app, create your methods that utilize the code below:

```js
// windows: "cmd","/c"
// unix: "/bin/sh","-c"
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","mvn","test");
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = builder.start();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
// code to process test result from reader
// I only need to send this back to as API response. So there were no other impl
```